# calling xll function python

Tags: python, excel, xll

Hi I am trying to call a function of an xll addin through python. I have loaded the addin and everything runs fine, up to the point where I need to call a function where I an argument is optional and thus I can leave it blank, and then I get an error. Namely:
in excel, `function1` works fine if i type in a cell

```
=function1('a','b',,'d')
```

but if in python I write:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from win32com.client import Dispatch
Path  = 'myWeirdApp.xll'
xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlApp.RegisterXLL(Path)
```

the following line doesn't work:

```
xllApp.run('function1', 'a','b', , 'd')
```

does anybody have a solution for this type of situation?

Comment: Hi. I also have some xll add-in that I want to be able to load and use in python. Can you please share your solution? Thanks

Comment: `xllApp` is a typo, this should read  `xlApp.run('function1', ...)`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like that if you substitute the gaps with `None` it works fine!